# Drop down menu is Glitchy at the edge of menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have an odd issue. I created a standard dropdown menu but I am having an issue where the menu is dissapearing when I get right between the menu and the drop down. I cant find any css that would stop the hover state but maybe your eyes are better than mine.

Here is a gif of what is happening: http://imgur.com/axF6skK

My js code:

```
//------- NAV MENU --------//
$('nav li').hover(
  function () {
    $('ul', this).stop(true,true).fadeIn({ duration: 300, queue: false }).slideDown(300);
  },
  function () {
    $('ul', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut({ duration: 300, queue: false }).slideUp(300);
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="center">
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
      <a class="inactive">Get Started</a>
      <ul class="dropdown hidden" id="drop1">
        <li class="dropitem"><a href="#Start">Start Making Your CCR</a></li>
        <li class="dropitem"><a href="#HowItWorks">How CCR Writer Works</a></li>
        <li class="dropitem"><a href="#Why">Why Choose CCR Writer</a></li>
        <li class="dropitem"><a href="#MyPrevious">Access My Previous CCRs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
nav > ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

li.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

li.menu:hover { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

li.menu a {
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-top: 33px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

li.menu:hover a { color: #232323; }

li.dropitem {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.dropitem:hover { background-color: #DADADA; }

li.dropitem a {
  color: #232323;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to remove `z-index: -1` from `ul.dropdown` ? - I think that'll fix it

Comment: you could also change li.menu {
  display: table-cell; } or li.menu { z-index: 1; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `z-index: -1` from this CSS:

```
ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /* z-index: -1; */       /* <-- Remove this line */
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use  `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: inline-block`.

```
li.menu {
  display: display: inline-flex;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is this something that is general practice type thing or is there some other reason to use inline-flex instead of inline-block?

Comment: I can't tell that it is a general practice but most of developers use display: list-item on the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `z-index` on `ul.dropdown`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue just by changing the parameters in `stop()` from `true` to `false`:

```
$('nav li').hover(
  function () {
    $("ul",this).stop(false,false).fadeIn({ duration: 300, queue: false }).slideDown(300);
  },
  function () {
    $("ul",this).stop(false,false).fadeOut({ duration: 300, queue: false }).slideUp(300);
});
```

As you can see on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwdf8fhc/